# ¿Como validar un campo en html?

Tags: html, required

lo que quiero hacer es validar un campo en html, donde tenga que ingresar mínimo una letra para que me deje avanzar, está validado con require solamente pero si agrego un espacio al campo me deja enviar el espacio nadamas y eso en la base se inserta.
Alguien sabe de alguna forma para que como mínimo me pida ingresar una letra y si tiene solo uno o muchos espacios no deje avanzar?

les dejo esta parte de mi codigo donde hago el required

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actividad realizada</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Actividad realizada" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripcion de actividad</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Si me pudieran ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola, si quieres una mejor respuesta deberías indicar cómo envías el formulario (Ej: Botón Submit, jQuery) y qué frameworks usas (Ej: jQuery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo si envías el formulario con un botón submit. La solución a tu problema sería el atributo pattern. De esta forma no acepta ningún espacio ni carácter especial y cómo mínimo debes introducir un carácter. Puedes averiguar más combinaciones si lo buscas en internet.
Saludos.

```html
<form>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" pattern="[A-Za-z]" placeholder="Actividad realizada" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```